# What is the difference between cancelling and exiting a pthread?

Tags: linux, pthreads

The term "cancelling a pthread" and "exiting a pthread" looks confusing.
Can someone help me clearly explain the difference between the two?

P.S: Please don't help me with a link to the man pages, i have already seen that :-)

**Added:**

> 1) How are the thread data structures handled, and the cleanup
>   different in both these cases?
>
> 2) When there are signals pending for a thread, how are the pending
>   signals mask handled in both these cases?

Comment: Cancelling a thread is something initiated from outside the thread and takes great care to ensure that cancellation is done correctly (and that resources that might be held by the thread are properly released). Exiting a thread is something the thread does when it determines it should, much like returning from a function.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: how are the thread data structures handled, and the cleanup different in both these cases? When there are signals pending for a thread, how are the pending signals mask handled in both these cases again?

Comment: those are questions I don't have the expertise to answer (hence my rather high-level comment). Also, your question didn't make it seem that you were looking for that level of detail; you might want to add the questions you had in your comment to the top-level question.

Comment: As you say you already read the man pages, I at least wonder about the first question in your addendum, as it's answered in `man 3 pthread_cancel`.

Comment: @alk: It just says: `Any cancellation cleanup handlers that have been pushed and not yet popped are popped in the reverse order that they were pushed and then executed` same for both cases, this is a little vague, and at a high level (I feel). Please note carefully that my question is related to difference between the two, not the similarity, which the man page highlights.

Comment: I do not see what's *vague* with this. However, if everything is similiar, one could conculde there is no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring the 1st question in the OP's addendum, verbatim from `man pthread_cancel()`:

> When a cancellation requested is acted on, the following steps occur for thread (in this order):
>
> 1. Cancellation clean-up handlers are popped (in the reverse of the order in which they were pushed) and called.  (See **pthread_cleanup_push(3)**.)
> 2. Thread-specific data destructors are called, in an unspecified order.  (See **pthread_key_create(3)**.)
> 3. The thread is terminated.  (See **pthread_exit(3)**.)
>
> The above steps happen asynchronously with respect to the **pthread_cancel()** call; the return status of **pthread_cancel()** merely informs the caller whether the cancellation request was successfully queued.
>
> After a canceled thread has terminated, a join with that thread using **pthread_join(3)** obtains PTHREAD_CANCELED as the thread's exit status.  (Joining with a thread is the only way to know that cancellation has completed.)

The only difference I see is the exit point: For a cancelled thread it's any cancellation point the thread function might pass, else it's `pthread_exit()`, `return` or the end of the thread function.

---

**Update** (referring the 2nd question):

I'd say if a signal was put into a thread's queue and still is pending when cancellation has finished the signal is lost. I'm not sure but I could imagine that signal processing is going on as long as the thread lives, that is also "during" the cancellation.

All I could find regarding this is from `man pthread_exit`:

> **BUGS**
>
> Currently, there are limitations in the kernel implementation logic for **wait(2)** ing on a stopped thread group with a dead thread group leader.  This can manifest in problems such as a locked terminal if a stop signal is  sent to a foreground process whose thread group leader has already called **pthread_exit(3)**.

---

All quotes are comming from the Debian (non-free) package [`manpages-posix-dev (2.16-1)`](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/m/manpages-posix/manpages-posix_2.16-1.tar.gz%60) . (The [source package is here](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/manpages-posix).)

Comment: Exactly the same two points, are mentioned for pthread_exit as well,  cleanup, which is confusing? Or is there any difference? How about the signals, any hint about that too?

Comment: Appreciate if you can suggest sumthng on the later part would be of great help.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: What exactly confused you? Also, please see my update answer.

Comment: This man page  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html does not specify abt signals, can you post the one you are referring to? Would be of great help for reference for us.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: I quoted the man pages from the current Debian stable release.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: I added links to my answer to where the quoted man pages came from. Also your link seems a bit out dated. The current is this one: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/